# ExtJS: Hidden column in grid showing data on store reload

Tags: extjs, grid, store

I have a grid.Panel configured as follows:

```
var myGrid = new Ext.grid.Panel({
                id:'myGridID',
                layout:'anchor',
                title:'My Grid',
                border: false,
                store:myStore,
                frame:false,
                columns:[{header: 'ID', hidden:true, hideable:false, dataIndex: 'data_id'},
                {header:'Title', flex:0.3, sortable:true, dataIndex:'data_title'},
                 {header:'Description', flex:0.7, sortable:true, dataIndex:'data_description'}]
....
```

Its supposed to show columns Title and Description and keep column ID hidden (I have to keep the column there because I need to get the ID of the selected record).

When my web page launches I load the data in the grid perfectly. The first column (the one with header ID) is hidden as its supposed to be and columns Title and Description show just fine.
The problem is that when I reload the store after adding a record to it the grids headers show fine (only Title and Description) but the data of column ID is also shown.

I used this line to reload the store:

```
Ext.getCmp('myGridID').getStore().load()
```

I found that if I resize any column (Title or Description), the data from column ID disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use 'hideable:false'? I don't think you should specify that, seems useless. Try running the code without it.

Comment: Its been quite a while since I asked this so I already changed it. By that time I wasn't aware that grids handle records, so I didn't have to load the id in the grid to actually use it. 

But going back to your answer I think I used hideable:false because if I didn't the user could "unhide" the column from the menu above the grid that allows users to hide columns.
By setting hideable:false the column ID didn't appear (or was disabled) in there so the user couldn't hide nor show that column.